# Incorrect ad_set targeting while creating Ad for PAGE_LIKES objectives

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-target-audience

Using marketing API, i'm creating Ad to promote page with campaign objective: "PAGE_LIKES". Campaign is successfully creating but when it's goes for AD_SET creation, show this error:

> "Incorrect Targeting for Ad Set"

i'm using this target object.

```
targeting: {
                    age_min: 18,
                    geo_locations: geo_locations,
                    locales: [6],
                    genders: gender_list,
                    interests: interests_list
                }
```

this object is working fine with objectives (REACH, IMPRESSION)etc,
So suggest me any solution

Answer (score 0):

If the campaign is for Page Likes, the targeting of the Ad Sets needs to exclude current fans of your page, via the `excluded_connections` parameter (specifying the page ID of the page you're promoting)

Try this:

```
targeting: {
                    age_min: 18,
                    geo_locations: geo_locations,
                    locales: [6],
                    genders: gender_list,
                    interests: interests_list,
                    excluded_connections: [{'id': <PAGE ID HERE>}]
                }
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-specs/ under **Facebook Connections**